# How to display Widget Icon over Google Map Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter

In my application there is a google map. I used [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) for it. I want to add notification icon on right corner. I tried with Stack but Google Map overlay the icon.

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wA3i.png)

[This is I achived after comment google map code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxgR4.png)

[This is my current screen with below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi6et.png)

Code

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
          top: 60,
          right: 40,
          child: IconButton(
            icon: new Image.asset(UIData.notificationIcon),
            onPressed: () {},
          )),
      GoogleMap(
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
          markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
          onMapCreated: (controller) {
            if (this.mounted)
              setState(() {
                myController = controller;
              });
          })
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just shift bell icon below google map, try replacing below code, it's working my side perfectly

[image]

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  body: Stack(
children: <Widget>[
  GoogleMap(
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
      markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
      onMapCreated: (controller) {
        if (this.mounted)
          setState(() {
            myController = controller;
          });
      }),
  Positioned(
      top: 60,
      right: 40,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: new Image.asset(UIData.notificationIcon),
        onPressed: () {},
      )),
    ],
  ),
);
```